# Xamarin Forms Images never shown in any way

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I know there are already some questions about this situation but I've not found a solution even following literally some youtube videos.
My situation is the followed:

- I've started a new Xamarin form application that supports Android and iOS (I don't know why only these ones and not even Windows10 and Windows Phone)
- I've tried to put an Image inside the MainPage with a specific local or remote image but nothing seems to be shown

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:liveband"
             x:Class="liveband.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Image
            WidthRequest="200"
            HeightRequest="150"
            x:Name="MyImage"/>

        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        <Slider />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace liveband
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyImage.Source = new UriImageSource()
            {
                Uri = new Uri("http://www.satsignal.eu/wxsat/Meteosat7-full-scan.jpg")
            };
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I tested your code and can't reproduce your issue? The image shows well by my side, or maybe you could try to code like this `MyImage.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("http://www.satsignal.eu/wxsat/Meteosat7-full-scan.jpg"));`